# Visual Studio debugger starts Solution build

Tags: visual-studio, build, .net-5, visual-studio-debugging

I've designed a Visual Studio 2022 solution that contains 6 projects.  One produces an executable (.exe) and the others produce dlls that are consumed by the executable.  I've noticed that when I try to debug the executable, Visual Studio starts a build for the solution every time I debug.  I'm at a loss as to why it builds the solution when nothing has changed in any project.  I'm assuming that something in a project is causing the build to occur, but, I don't know what that may be.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Update: This solution is built for.Net5.  I found this setting in the options under SDK-Style projects that does not appear to work.

[image]

Comment: Could you please open the build configuration and check if building the solution or building the projects is activated?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but, all projects in the solution are set to build in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post, "[Visual Studio not auto-building when I press the debug button](https://superuser.com/questions/135627/visual-studio-not-auto-building-when-i-press-the-debug-button)" solved my problem.  I set the following to force Visual Studio to NOT build each time I started the debugger.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build And Run, set MSBuild output to Detailed, build the project, check the output log.
You can also try resetting all settings.

Comment: This does not work since the output window is cleared after the build and filled with debug info.